# Cordova: How to detect if push notifications are disabled on the device?

Tags: cordova, notifications, push

I need a way to find out if the user has disabled the push notifications for my app on his device or not. So far I have tried this

```
pushNotification.register(apnSuccessfulRegistration,
  apnFailedRegistration, { 
    "badge": "true",
    "sound": "true",
    "alert": "true",
    "ecb": "pushCallbacks.onNotification"
});
```

The `apnSuccessfulRegistration` is triggered when the Notifications are ENABLED on the device.

The `apnSuccessfulRegistration` AND `apnFailedRegistration` are not triggered when the notifications are DISABLED on the device.

Anyone can give me a hint ?

P.S: I'm using Cordova version: 3.5.0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the official push notification plugin `com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin` , they've had an issue open for that for a while now:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/162

so, even with the latest version (2.4.0.) the problem persists. In that very thread they propose a workaround, mind it is not nice, which is basically a timeout that sets a global variable if you do not get a response from the plugin.

```
pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
    "badge":"false",
    "sound":"true",
    "alert":"true",
    "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
});
// We assume that if the register callback hasn't happened
// within 2 seconds, there must have been some error.
setTimeout(errorHandler, 2000);
```

I copied that from the link above.